# Unity view Registered Types during debug

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, unity-container

Possibly a stupid question, but during debug I simply want to see the types that have been registered with my Unity container. I have tried going through the container in the watch window, but can't seem to find what I am looking for? I am expecting there to be a list of registered types somewhere?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, I have used Windsor before and managed to get that information. I am forced to use Unity at the moment and need to know how to do it for Unity specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is in there but it's pretty buried. Usually I use the following extension:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;

namespace NBody.Viewer.Unity

{
    public class QueryableContainerExtension : UnityContainerExtension
    {
        private List<RegisterEventArgs> _registrations;
        public IList<RegisterEventArgs> Registrations
        {
            get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<RegisterEventArgs>(_registrations); }
        }

        private List<RegisterInstanceEventArgs> _instanceRegistrations;
        public IList<RegisterInstanceEventArgs> InstanceRegistrations
        {
            get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<RegisterInstanceEventArgs>(_instanceRegistrations); }
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            _registrations = new List<RegisterEventArgs>();
            _instanceRegistrations = new List<RegisterInstanceEventArgs>();
            Context.Registering += (s, e) => _registrations.Add(e);
            Context.RegisteringInstance += (s, e) => _instanceRegistrations.Add(e);
        }

        public bool IsTypeRegistered<TFrom, TTo>()
        {
            return _registrations.Exists(e => e.TypeFrom == typeof(TFrom) && e.TypeTo == typeof(TTo));
        }

        public bool IsTypeRegistered<TFrom>()
        {
            return _registrations.Exists(e => e.TypeFrom == typeof(TFrom));
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can write code like this:

```
    [Fact]
    public void IsTypeRegisteredReturnsTrueForRegisteredType()
    {
        QueryableContainerExtension target = new QueryableContainerExtension();
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        container.AddExtension(target);

        container.RegisterType<IEnumerable, Array>();

        Assert.True(target.IsTypeRegistered<IEnumerable, Array>());
        Assert.True(target.IsTypeRegistered<IEnumerable>());
        Assert.False(target.IsTypeRegistered<IEnumerable, SortedList>());
        Assert.False(target.IsTypeRegistered<IList>());
    }
```

You could use this approach or you could wrap or alter the source for the container to add a DebuggerDisplay attribute and a method which uses the above code to iterate through the  container contents.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unity 2.0 supports a container Registrations enumeration and IsRegistered method which makes the above code obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to register an extension for that.
In the debugger view of the container simply expand "Registrations" 
There expand the "Results View" marked by the circle with the two arrows.
This will enumerate the registrations and you can expand them.

[image: Unity container view]

Comment: It's not exactly pretty... in your screenshot I can't see a single registration displayed, suggesting I'd have to drill down several layers? I tried to do this myself and quickly got lost!

Comment: @Mr.Boy You can use your favorite Json serializer, like Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(), to dump to the immediate window.